# Streaming OSX audio input channel to iOS

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I'm trying to create an app that records audio from an input device on my Mac and streams it to my iPhone and plays it. I've messed around with Core Audio for a few days and have managed to record audio from the device and save it to a file on my Mac. However, I haven't found a way to encode the audio stream and replay it on iOS.

I know how to handle the network part of sending data to the phone I'm unsure how to record it into a format acceptable for sending and then playing that buffer back out on the iPhone.

Any hints on where to look, example code, or projects that are similar would be appreciated.